# Displaying images blobs on Django html templates using SaS token

Tags: python, django, azure-storage

I'm currently trying to get blob images displayed in the HTML of Django templates using the SaS token but I don't see any online implementation examples.
I currently have the SaS token but don't know how to implement it in Django.

I tried to manually add the token to the end of the URL:

https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{path}.jpg/?sp=r&st=2023-03-11T17:53:36Z&se=2050-03-12T01:53:36Z&sv=2021-12-02&sr=c&sig={****}

Answer (score 0):

That looks roughly correct, except for the slash after "jpg". Here's an example of a URL I have in a Django app:

[https://djangoccrediszbokstorage.blob.core.windows.net/media/pf.png?se=2023-03-19T22%3A13%3A04Z&sp=r&sv=2021-12-02&sr=b&sig={***}](https://djangoccrediszbokstorage.blob.core.windows.net/media/pf.png?se=2023-03-19T22%3A13%3A04Z&sp=r&sv=2021-12-02&sr=b&sig=%7B***%7D)

You can use [django-storages](https://pypi.org/project/django-storages) to generate URLs for you, by the way. That's what I used in that app.